# Screen brightness turns to the minimum when I try to change it

Tags: multiple-monitors, laptop, brightness

I have a dual monitor setup, one is my laptop's screen and the other one is a normal monitor.

When I start up Ubuntu everything's fine, but when I try changing the brightness of my laptop's monitor (using the built-in function keys), the brightness lowers itself to the minimum. This only happens the first time I try changing the brightness, so it's as if the brightness started on zero, but does not take effect until I try changing it.

This is just a minor problem, but I'd like to fix it if it is possible.

Any ideas?

Edit: Just in case, my laptop is the Lenovo Ideapad 3 14ADA05, my other monitor is a Samsung 42 inch TV (I don't know its name), I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.01, release 5.8.0-48 generic.

Comment: What OS & release are you using?   If a desktop system, the desktop itself should also be provided if it's not the default for your release.  FYI:  I did some *testing* for a *flavor* a number of cycles ago (*eoan* maybe) and found many devices were unique & some acted different when external monitor was attached.. so solution maybe hardware specific.. but you've not provided the basics of your software stack...

Comment: Sorry for that @guiverc! My laptop is the Lenovo Ideapad 3 14ADA05, my other monitor is a Samsung 42 inch TV (I don't know its name), I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.01, release 5.8.0-48 generic. If you need anything else feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

This is me from another account. I finally found a solution for my problem (although it seems rather 'hacky', but hey, at least it works!)

Using [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30924/how-do-i-set-default-brightness-after-boot) as a guide, I created the `/etc/rc.local` file (which for some reason I do not know of, was not there in the first place), with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
sh /home/dante/scripts/initial_brightness.sh
```

This runs the following script on reboot, which sets the initial brightness to the maximum, so when I try to change it, it does not go back to the minimum possible value anymore.

```
#!/bin/sh
cat /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/max_brightness > /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness
```

In my case, these files were located inside `amdgpu_bl0`, but I believe it can vary from system to system.

Remember to make both `/etc/rc.local` and `initial_brightness.sh` executable, using `sudo chmod 755 (script location)`, and make root own `/etc/rc.local` using `sudo chown root /etc/rc.local`.

On a side note, for obvious reasons I won't be marking this answer as accepted, since it feels like cheating if I mark my own answer on another account, but I'll post it in the hopes of helping anyone who has the same problem as me.